# NameError: name 'mp_image' is not defined with MediaPipe gesture recognition

Tags: python, nameerror, mediapipe

I am trying to utilize MediaPipe for real-time gesture recognition over a webcam. However, I want to use the `gesture_recognizer.task` model for inference. Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe.tasks import python
from mediapipe.tasks.python import vision

model_path = "gesture_recognizer.task"
base_options = python.BaseOptions(model_asset_path=model_path)
GestureRecognizer = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizer
GestureRecognizerOptions = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizerOptions
GestureRecognizerResult = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizerResult
VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode

def print_result(result: GestureRecognizerResult, output_image: mp.Image, timestamp_ms: int):
    print('gesture recognition result: {}'.format(result))

options = GestureRecognizerOptions(
    base_options=python.BaseOptions(model_asset_path=model_path),
    running_mode=VisionRunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
    result_callback=print_result)
recognizer = GestureRecognizer.create_from_options(options)

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mp_hands.Hands(
        static_image_mode=False,
        max_num_hands=2,
        min_detection_confidence=0.65,
        min_tracking_confidence=0.65)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
        
    i = 1  # left or right hand
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = hands.process(frame)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    np_array = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            h, w, c = frame.shape
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, hand_landmarks, mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
            mp_image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=np_array)
            results = recognizer.recognize_async(mp_image)
    
    # show the prediction on the frame
    cv2.putText(mp_image, results, (10, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                   1, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Hands', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cap.release()
```

I am getting a `NameError: name 'mp_image' is not defined` error on the line `cv2.putText(mp_image, results, (10, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)`. By now I am really confused and not sure what I am doing, let alone what I am doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: Presumably that loop body where `mp_image` is defined was never run.

Comment: How to deal with it? TBH I am at a loss right now, you know how it feels at times when you have been trying to write a code and then you just feel lost.

Comment: in line 51, move cv2.putText to outside of for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to all the changes mentioned in the comments, you should also provide a "monotonically increasing" timestamp to the `recognize_async()` function.
Since the `recognize_callback` cannot access the output image directly, I have used a lock and a shared field to share gesture data between the threads. This is a fully functional example (mediapipe==0.10.0):

```py
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe.tasks import python
import threading 

class GestureRecognizer:
    def main(self):
        num_hands = 2
        model_path = "gesture_recognizer.task"
        GestureRecognizer = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizer
        GestureRecognizerOptions = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizerOptions
        VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode

        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.current_gestures = []
        options = GestureRecognizerOptions(
            base_options=python.BaseOptions(model_asset_path=model_path),
            running_mode=VisionRunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
            num_hands = num_hands,
            result_callback=self.__result_callback)
        recognizer = GestureRecognizer.create_from_options(options)

        timestamp = 0 
        mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
        hands = mp_hands.Hands(
                static_image_mode=False,
                max_num_hands=num_hands,
                min_detection_confidence=0.65,
                min_tracking_confidence=0.65)

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            results = hands.process(frame)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            np_array = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            
            if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, hand_landmarks, mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
                    mp_image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=np_array)
                    recognizer.recognize_async(mp_image, timestamp)
                    timestamp = timestamp + 1 # should be monotonically increasing, because in LIVE_STREAM mode
                    
                self.put_gestures(frame)

            cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Hands', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
                break

        cap.release()

    def put_gestures(self, frame):
        self.lock.acquire()
        gestures = self.current_gestures
        self.lock.release()
        y_pos = 50
        for hand_gesture_name in gestures:
            # show the prediction on the frame
            cv2.putText(frame, hand_gesture_name, (10, y_pos), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                                1, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            y_pos += 50

    def __result_callback(self, result, output_image, timestamp_ms):
        #print(f'gesture recognition result: {result}')
        self.lock.acquire() # solves potential concurrency issues
        self.current_gestures = []
        if result is not None and any(result.gestures):
            print("Recognized gestures:")
            for single_hand_gesture_data in result.gestures:
                gesture_name = single_hand_gesture_data[0].category_name
                print(gesture_name)
                self.current_gestures.append(gesture_name)
        self.lock.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rec = GestureRecognizer()
    rec.main()
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. StackOverflow says I can award the bounty only after 14 hours, I will give it to you asap. Although, I have already marked your answer as the correct solution. I am trying to build something that would benefit a lot of people, I cannot do it alone. Was wondering if you would be interested in collaborating. I understand being a Prof you are a busy person, however, I would need you as an advisor. You can check my LinkedIn profile if you want. Thanks so much.